# How to get language ID for a language culture in nopCommerce 3.9?

Tags: c#, nopcommerce

Working with nopCommerce 3.9 how can find out the LanguageId (the ID stored in the nopCommerce DataBase) for a language if I only know the language culture?

For instance, when I want to add a locale resource in the `Install()` method of my plugin, I can achieve that by specifying the culture as string value

```
this.AddOrUpdatePluginLocaleResource("Plugins.Payment.CheckMoneyOrder.AdditionalFee",
     "Additional fee", "en-US");
```

But other methods require the language ID and don't accept a culture string. (e.g. the `SaveLocalizedSetting` extension method for settings)

```
checkMoneyOrderPaymentSettings.SaveLocalizedSetting(x => x.DescriptionText,
                    languageId, //how to find out the ID for "en-US"
                    "my localized text");
```

How can I get the ID for "en-US" if I only know the locale resource at that point of execution?

Comment: What language ID? Do you mean `CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US").LCID` or similar?

Comment: The language ID that is stored in the nopCommerce database (I updated my question)

Comment: Why you do not do this this same way, as nopCommerce do it? checkMoneyOrderPaymentSettings.SaveLocalizedSetting(x => x.DescriptionText,
                    localized.LanguageId,
                    localized.DescriptionText);

Comment: @Tomu because I want to do it in the `Install()`method of the plugin. There I don't have a `localized` instance but multiple cultures ("en-US", "de-DE" etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try bellow code. Add reference Nop.Services at your plugin.

```
var langId = _languageService.GetAllLanguages().Where(x => x.LanguageCulture == "en-US").FirstOrDefault().Id;
```